# categorizing suites in allure report, In suites tab

Tags: jasmine, protractor, allure, test-suite, gulp-protractor

We are using allure to generate report for our jasmine protractor test suite.

All suites are shown in suites tab with respective tests

Is there any way that I can categorize suites,based on different group names for the suites like smoke, Sanity...

Below is the requirement

```
-----SmokeSuite
        -----------testsuite1
                        -----Test1
                        -----Test2
                        -----Test3
        -----------testsuite2
                        -----Test1
                        -----Test2
                        -----Test3

-----SanitySuite
        -----------testsuite1
                        ------Test1
                        ------Test2
                        ------Test3
        -----------testsuite2
                        -----Test1
                        -----Test2
                        -----Test3
-----RegressionSuite
        -----------testsuite1
                        ------Test1
                        ------Test2
                        ------Test3
        -----------testsuite2
                        -----Test1
                        -----Test2
                        -----Test3
```